# ¿Como comparar dos arreglos multidimensionales con JavaScript con filter()?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Quiero ir agrandando el arreglo "OldData", por lo tanto me llega un nuevo arreglo "newData", quiero saber si los IDS de "newData" ya están en "oldData", agregar solo los que no esten, en este caso `["4", "Xperia 10", "Sony"]`

```
let oldData = [
  ["1", "iPhone", "Apple"],
  ["2", "SSG10", "Samsung"],
  ["3", "Nexus", "Google"]
]

let newData = [
  ["1", "iPhone", "Apple"],
  ["2", "SSG10", "Samsung"],
  ["3", "Nexus", "Google"],
  ["4", "Xperia 10", "Sony"],
]
```

He intentando con un 'for loop' y me funciona, pero quiero saber como usar "FILTER".

```
for(var i=0; i<newData.length; i++){
    var match = false;
    for(var j=0; i<oldData.length & !match; j++){
       if(newData[i][0] == oldData[j][0]){
          match = true;
       }
     }
        
      if(!match){
        oldData.push(oldData[i]);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero podrías recorrer `oldData`, en donde dentro podrás ir filtrando `newData` por el id para que solo te queden aquellos cuyo id no se encuentra en `oldData`, para luego simplemente adicionarlo con un `concat` al arreglo anterior.

En este caso uso el filtro en el cual mediante el comando `filter` le digo que el id que me muestre solo aquellos que tengan un id distinto por eso uso la posición `0`.

```js
let oldData = [
  ["1", "iPhone", "Apple"],
  ["2", "SSG10", "Samsung"],
  ["3", "Nexus", "Google"]
]

let newData = [
  ["1", "iPhone", "Apple"],
  ["2", "SSG10", "Samsung"],
  ["3", "Nexus", "Google"],
  ["4", "Xperia 10", "Sony"],
]

function validate(){
    for (var j = 0; j < oldData.length; j++) {
      newData= newData.filter(obj => obj[0] != oldData[j][0]);
    }
    oldData = oldData.concat(newData);
    console.log(oldData);
}

validate();
```

Answer (score 1):

Usando solo métodos de arreglos:

- [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) recorre el arreglo y devuelve solo los elementos que cumplan con la condición
- [.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) devuelve -1 si el elemento no existe en el arreglo o la posición que ocupa en caso de existir

  - La condición *"(resultado de findIndex) < 0"* es: Si el elemento de `newData` no existe en `oldData`, agregarlo a los resultados de filter; de lo contrario, se omite
- [.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) agrega los elementos resultantes del filtro y la notación `...nombreDeArreglo` es para evitar crear otro ciclo, simplemente [desestructurando los datos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
let oldData = [
  ["1", "iPhone", "Apple"],
  ["2", "SSG10", "Samsung"],
  ["3", "Nexus", "Google"]
];

let newData = [
  ["1", "iPhone", "Apple"],
  ["2", "SSG10", "Samsung"],
  ["3", "Nexus", "Google"],
  ["4", "Xperia 10", "Sony"],
];

let noRepeat = newData.filter(item => oldData.findIndex(old => old[0] == item[0]) < 0);
// Agregar elementos al arreglo original
oldData.push(...noRepeat);

console.log(oldData);
```

Otra forma más adecuada sería usando `.map()` en lugar de `.filter()`, para recorrer el arreglo y agregar directamente los elementos que no existan en el original:

```js
let oldData = [
  ["1", "iPhone", "Apple"],
  ["2", "SSG10", "Samsung"],
  ["3", "Nexus", "Google"]
];

let newData = [
  ["1", "iPhone", "Apple"],
  ["2", "SSG10", "Samsung"],
  ["3", "Nexus", "Google"],
  ["4", "Xperia 10", "Sony"],
];

newData.map(item => {
    if(oldData.findIndex(old => old[0] == item[0]) < 0) {
        // El elemento no existe en el arreglo original, se agrega aquí
        oldData.push(item);
    }
});

console.log(oldData);
```